# formatting JSON object in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, json

I have a rails app has an api for iphone/android clients. I'm doing Message.find(1).to_json(:include => :user) but that adds \ around " to escape it.

How can I prevent to_json from escaping the double quotes?

```
>> { "a" => "blah" }.to_json
=> "{\"a\":\"blah\"}"
```

I would like it to be `{ "a" : "blah" }` or `{ a : "blah" }`

Comment: this is escaping stuff, why do you want to remove it?

Comment: json parsing on the iOS side fails because it has \ around quotes. With this app, there will never be any quotes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is actually what you want.

What you are seeing is the string formatted for display (and human readability).  It is delimited by double quotes, so the double quotes *inside the string* are escaped.  In reality, the string contains double quotes, but for literal representation, they are escaped.  If you stick this into a JSON parser you will find it returns the object you want.

If you were to print this out, you will find that you get the format you want.

```
irb(main):001:0> puts { "a" => "blah" }.to_json
{"a":"blah"}
=> nil
```

For further illustration, you could try parsing it.  The string you ended up with returns your original object, because JSON is represented by a string.  However, attempting to insert the desired content will give you a nasty syntax error or a TypeError.  This is because JSON is not a literal in Ruby, whereas in JavaScript it can be used as a literal object.  In Ruby it is a representation in the form of a string.

```
irb(main):002:0> JSON.parse("{\"a\":\"blah\"}")
=> {"a"=>"blah"}

irb(main):003:0> JSON.parse({ "a" : "blah" })
SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
JSON.parse({ "a" : "blah" })
                  ^
(irb):3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
JSON.parse({ "a" : "blah" })
                       ^
irb(main):004:0> JSON.parse({a:"blah"})
TypeError: can't convert Hash into String
```

Comment: In irb, you can see the unquoted, unescaped string by calling puts on the result (i.e. puts { "a" => "blah" }.to_json).

Comment: Ah, duh.  I'll edit to avoid the roundabout way.  Where is my mind today.

Comment: I used as_json instead of to_json and that seems to work but I'm not sure what's the difference between the two

Comment: as_json is used to generate a hash structure to be encoded into json.

Comment: Is it possible you were doing this: render :json => @bla.to_json. If so, you may have been converting a string, which was already json, to json, thus doubly escaping it?